# How to filter 10 hours rows in DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a DataFrame in Spark 2 (Scala) in which one of the columns is a unix timestamp. I want to obtain only those rows that are within last 10 hours starting from now.

How can I do it?

```
val hours = 10
val result = df.filter($"unix_timestamp" > hours)
```

Comment: can you share the output of `df.select("unix_timestamp").show(1)` and `df.select("unix_timestamp").printSchema()`?

Answer (score 0):

With data:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{current_timestamp, expr}


val df = Seq(1517877887, 1517935463, 1517949824).toDF("unix_timestamp")
df.select($"unix_timestamp", $"unix_timestamp".cast("timestamp")).show
// +--------------+-------------------+
// |unix_timestamp|     unix_timestamp|
// +--------------+-------------------+
// |    1517877887|2018-02-06 00:44:47|
// |    1517935463|2018-02-06 16:44:23|
// |    1517949824|2018-02-06 20:43:44|
//+--------------+-------------------+

spark.sql("SELECT current_timestamp").show
// +--------------------+
// | current_timestamp()|
// +--------------------+
// |2018-02-06 20:47:...|
// +--------------------+
```

subtract `INTERVAL` expression:

```
val last10hours = df.where(
  $"unix_timestamp".cast("timestamp") > current_timestamp - expr("INTERVAL 10 hours")
)
```

which will give you:

```
last10hours.select($"unix_timestamp", $"unix_timestamp".cast("timestamp")).show
// +--------------+-------------------+
// |unix_timestamp|     unix_timestamp|
// +--------------+-------------------+
// |    1517935463|2018-02-06 16:44:23|
// |    1517949824|2018-02-06 20:43:44|
// +--------------+-------------------+
```

Reference [Adding 12 hours to datetime column in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40883084/8371915)

Comment: Why do you use `.cast("timestamp")` if the column contains unix timestamps?

Comment: If I have string date, can I do this operation? `.withColumn("mytimestamp", to_timestamp($"mydatetime")).where($"mytimestamp".cast("timestamp") > current_timestamp - expr("INTERVAL 10 hours"))`

Comment: It has to be `timestamp`, how is it done depend on your data. Normally we refer to Unix timestamp as number of seconds or milliseconds since epoch.